# ImportError: No module named setuptools

Tags: modules

I'm on RPI 4. I'm trying to install the RPIO module to control an ESC. When I type in the command `sudo python setup.py install` I get the error `ImportError: No module named setuptools`. When I install setuptools using the command `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` it prints out `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.` and when I try using the command `sudo python setup.py install` I get the same error even though I downloaded setuptools (for some reason nothing was changed or updated)

EDIT: I've tried installing [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/87825/this-module-can-only-be-run-on-a-raspberry-pi) way (1st answer) but when I type in the command `unzip RPIO-2.zip` I get`unzip:  cannot find or open RPIO-2.zip, RPIO-2.zip.zip or RPIO-2.zip.ZIP.`

Comment: RPIO seems very old, pigpiod might be better https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76111/esc-control-with-rpi-gpio-pins

Comment: **Are you sure it works on the Pi4?**  The software stopped development before that model which had significant changes from the earlier models,